# jQuery - Access object property

Tags: jquery, jplayer

For unit testing purpose, I need to check the *src* object property of a jQuery & jPlayer object.
Unfortunately, I can't get though accessing the property via DOM.

Here is the init code for reference :

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "mysound.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play"));
    }
(...)
```

Firebug tells my property is available at :

```
jPlayer.status.src
```

But the following code returns an undefined.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer().status.src
```

This also returns an undefined.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer.status.src
```

What would be the correct path command to call and grab the *src* value ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves me correctly, I think its something like...

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.src
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That should deserve a beer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a property of the object the function jPlayer returns. However the firebug output you've posted says it's not a property of the return value but a property of the function it self. jPlayer is both a function and an object with properties. All functions in JS are objects that can have properties like any other object
so

```
jPlayer.status.src
```

accesses the src property of the status property of the function/object identified by jPlayer
whereas

```
jPlayer().status.src
```

accesses the src property of the status property of the object returned by calling the function identified by jPlayer

as per the comment

$(...).jPlayer

is a property of the jQuery selector (one attached through the jPlayer plug-in) that property does not have to be the same as identified by the `jPlayer`identifier. The `jPlayer`identifier is actually a property of the global object so they might or they might not be the same. In your case they are not the same or the line from firebug is incorrect/incomplete

Comment: Thank for the reply. As previously discussed here (but removed by admin), I should have mentioned that `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer.status.src` also returns a undefined.